# Custom theme for users in a SPA (Angular 2) web app

Tags: angular, cookies, architecture, themes, single-page-application

For SPA web applications (Angular 2 in this case), how do you go about providing custom themes (color schemes) for different users in the application? These themes need to persist between sessions, so the data has to be stored server-side and retrieved by the client or preloaded by the server, but I'm not sure how to approach this to begin with.

I think the ideal approach is some preloading strategy by the server as retrieving theme information from the client would cause too much delay on initial app load. But, given I don't know how this would look like with either approach, any feedback is much appreciated.

*Additional Considerations:*

- Not using Angular Universal so that isn't an option.
- Using Angular Material, so custom material theming templates can be created/generated and used. Was thinking maybe storing the value for which material template to use in a cookie and retrieving that from the cookie could be an option, but not sure how to generate and have Angular 2 use the template. In addition, if there are thousands of users, the file for the templates would become unmanageably large.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is allow users to create "blocks" "partials", which then they could use to glue together.

Your DB will then reference the user generated dom structure that directly relates your schema tree.